# Android Weather App WeatherIcon issue

Tags: android, imageview, weather-api

I am trying to make a weather app on android studio. I previously made the application as a desktop application in java. I currently have everything working in the android version, except i cannot figure out how to change the image of the weather icon to change based off of the updated weather. I can only make a it a permanent image/icon

below is the main activity class

```
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Context context = img.getContext();
        img.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + w.getWeather(), null, context.getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Have you considered using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for REST API access, and http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate the model object you're manually parsing in 200 lines, and maybe give your textview's some IDs that actually specify what they are beyond being `textView[N]` (using Refactor -> Rename, more specifically Shift+F6 on the ID)? Just wondering

Comment: I need to do it manually for an assignment. and it is a group project. Our group pre established those names and we just kept them.........Any idea how to help with the image?

Comment: This is a lot of code... Android doesn't even use main methods, so not sure what you are trying to show. If you are asking about `"drawable/" + w.getWeather()`, then please only show a [mcve]

Comment: Along with that point - we don't need to see 5 similar AsyncTasks of the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but this isn't verifiable or complete. What is the value of `w.getWeather()` ? How does it get set? Do you have that drawable resource?

Comment: sounds good man, still just learning my code wont be perfect but its getting the job done other than one part. And you were right about which part i was talking about.  the idea behind the long code put in the question was to show were the w.getWeather was coming from. I figure the more info the better..........now that the post is updated, is there anyway you can help me. i guess what i am wondering is if you can make the drawable portion a variable? because this i how i would think you do it, but unfortunately the image does not update with getWeather

Comment: and yes i have all of the drawable resources images that i want/need saved in the drawable resource director

Comment: w.getWeather() retrieves the current weather condition from the WeatherUnderground website. The images that are saved have the same file names that correspond exactly with the name of the weather condition recieved. and im pulling all of the info from a json document